# Duplicity Script to backup to Ubuntu one account

Tags: ubuntu-one, duplicity

Is there a duplicity script available to run [cron] from root and backup /home directories (no matter how many Users I have) to a UBUNTU ONE Cloud Account.  I will want to exclude all their /Downloads directories.